# Cannot render boxes from WSTP C++

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, boxes

I am attempting to send text from a WSTP `C++` backend to the Mathematica kernel which should be parsed and rendered as [boxes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#28564).

The goal is for the user to see the outputs of things like `Echo` as:

[image]

Frustratingly, when text like this is sent as a packet through WSTP, it does not render, and hides anything else in the string:

[image]

I construct the [string representation of the boxes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#28564) in `C++` through [raw string literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals) (having also tried explicit character escaping):

```
std::string x = R"delimiter(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[A,0]\))delimiter"
```

which, by writing to file, I have confirmed produces precisely the input to the `Echo` in my first example.

Yet when I send `Echo[x]` to the kernel through

```
WSPutFunction(stdlink, "EvaluatePacket", 1);
WSPutFunction(stdlink, "Echo", 1);
WSPutString(stdlink, x.c_str());
WSEndPacket(stdlink);
```

it doesn't render. What am I doing wrong?

Note that I must embed the boxes into larger strings. Ergo something like this workaround, letting the kernel generate the box strings, is not acceptable:

```
std::string expr = "Subscript[A,0]";

WSPutFunction(stdlink, "EvaluatePacket", 1);
WSPutFunction(stdlink, "Echo", 1);

// send StringJoin[..., ToString @ StandardForm @ ToExpression @ expr]
WSPutFunction(stdlink, "StringJoin", 2);
    WSPutString(stdlink, "message prefix or something: ");
    WSPutFunction(stdlink, "ToString", 1);
        WSPutFunction(stdlink, "StandardForm", 1);
            WSPutFunction(stdlink, "ToExpression", 1);
                WSPutString(stdlink, expr.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

A compromise is to let the kernel generate the boxes string and pass it back to the WSTP process, for concatenation with other strings as needed.

```
std::string local_getStandardFormFromMMA(std::string expr) {
    
    WSPutFunction(stdlink, "EvaluatePacket", 1);
    WSPutFunction(stdlink, "ToString", 1);
    WSPutFunction(stdlink, "StandardForm", 1);
    WSPutFunction(stdlink, "ToExpression", 1);
    WSPutString(stdlink, expr.c_str());
    WSEndPacket(stdlink);
    
    // I like to live dangerously
    long success;
    WSCheckFunction(stdlink, "ReturnPacket", &success);
    
    const char* response;
    WSGetString(stdlink, &response);
    std::string ret = std::string(response);
    WSReleaseString(stdlink, response);
    return ret;
}
```

Needlessly communicating with the kernel to obtain a string is still a small evil I'd like to avoid, so I will keep this question open.